# What are best practices for reducing cheating in online tests?

Tags: exams, cheating, online-learning, covid-19

I would like to know how can universities conduct exams of mathematical subjects during coronavirus.

My university is not willing to let us be tested from afar because of the claim that in this case, everyone would cheat and the grades wouldn't be truthful.

I think it's crazy to endanger the students for this reason (my country has a significant amount of coronavirus cases).

So I would like to know: how can an university deal with possibility of people cheating in online tests? I know prestigious institutions such as MIT, Harvard, etc, did online exams, so I don't see why my non-prestigious university can't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect cheating when students take online quizzes or exams from home?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/145102/how-to-detect-cheating-when-students-take-online-quizzes-or-exams-from-home)

Comment: I'm not sure the answer will be useful. I think people struggled with it and many, perhaps most, found it unsatisfactory. I agree that endangering people's health is probably the worst possible solution. Especially if people need to travel to an exam site by public transport.

Comment: Prestige has nothing to do with it - national culture does.  One reason that prestigious universities i the US might not worry so much about cheating is that, at a prestigious university in the US, almost no students fail (because the students that might fail wouldn't have been admitted) and grades are not taken that seriously.

Comment: Some based the grades on tests / assessments already completed.  Students who leave things to the last moment tend to find that unfair...

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: I would say less *national* culture and more *university* culture.  There are certainly other institutions in the US where I think people would be far more concerned about cheating.

Comment: @saraspagno, you can also take a look at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ which has several questions about online instruction and cheating, specifically about teaching math.